# AudioKit 4.9.3 on macOS Catalina: AKFrequencyTracker() & AKMicrophoneTracker() give bogus amplitude & frequency

Tags: audiokit

I've installed the AudioKit 4.9.3 framework to my macOS app according to instructions.

My App uses the Sandboxing capability, which XCode 11.3 under Catalina enables by default and checkmarked "Audio Input" item to allow mic access. AudioKit 4.9.3 says it supports sandboxing.

I've tried installing the pre-built frameworks, but it doesn't work.
I also built AudioKit from source and used those frameworks. Didn't work. I  used every documented approach I can find online for mic tracking, but I can't seem to detect microphone amplitude or frequency, whether I use AKMicrophoneTracker() or AKFrequencyTracker().

No amount of microphone input changes the frequency or amplitude values returned, it even though the preference pane shows mic activity on the built-in meter.

Configuration:

> **<sup>- Late 2015 iMac
>
> - macOS Catalina 10.15.2
>
> - Xcode 11.3
>
> - Latest AudioKit 4.9.3 for macOS
>
> - Tried with sandboxing disabled, and enabled (with Audio Input checked in capabilities).</sup>**

The latest approach I've used:

```
AudioKit.output = AKMixer()
do { 
   try AudioKit.start() 
} catch { 
   print("AudioKit start error") 
}
let tracker = AKMicrophoneTracker()
tracker.start()
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
    print(String(format:"%.3f", tracker.amplitude), tracker.frequency)
})
```

Displays:

**<sup>0.000 100.0</sup>**
**<sup>0.000 100.0</sup>**
**<sup>0.000 100.0</sup>**
**<sup>0.000 100.0</sup>**
**<sup>0.000 100.0</sup>**
**.**
**.**
**.**

*In all cases I see the following errors logged (at initialization), but many reports on the Internet is they are produced by the OS / internal framework.*

**<sup>2020-01-01 16:14:30.796714-0800 AudioKit_mic_tracking[36792:18467342] [plugin] 

    AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id 

    2020-01-01 16:14:30.823727-0800 

    AudioKit_mic_tracking[36792:18467342]
     HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine</sup>**

---

Comment: Do you get the same (lack of) result when using the "MicrophoneAnalysis" example in AudioKit?

Comment: Well, that's pretty bizarre, because part of AudioKit's build process is that every commit gets compiled on Travis Continuous Integration, which also builds all the included examples. So, we know that very least everything builds on a completely clean virtual machine.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka  Thanks for the feedback. I deleted my comments (no longer relevant) and put my feedback/conclusions into the answer after I got it resolved. Thanks for your help and suggestion!!!! Great project, and good work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Cause is an unthrown security exception***: After taking @AureliusProchazka's suggestion to try the example in the AudioKit 4.9.3 source distribution, and seeing the example app worked, I noticed it prompted at initialization to allow microphone access.  My application, where AudioKit did not work, *did not* prompt. Googling, I discovered the issue was that, as of macOS 10.14 there is device access security (similar to what iOS does to limit apps accessing location for example).

To pass the security check, any macOS app that uses the microphone MUST have the **`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`** property set the **`info.plist`**. That property triggers the OS to prompt the user for permission to use the device (microphone). Without that property, there will be *no prompt* and AudioKit will *silently fail*.

***Note about building AudioKit example code***: To build the MicrophoneAnalysis example, part of the full AudioKit source distribution: It wasn't enough to simply click the .xcodeproj file or open it from the menu, as works with many projects available online.

I still had to *manually* copy framework files into the XCode project, then add the files to the project to solve the problem of the import AudioKit statement in the example code not finding the 'AudioKit module'.

I'm pointing that out because, if you examine AudioKit example XCode project... after opening the .xcodeproj, you'll see framework libraries appear in the target's General settings under "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" section. In project's files,  AudioKit frameworks appear in the Frameworks group folder, with icons that look like packages (e.g. related frameworks seem to be present in the project!). That was a little misleading. They are placeholders or broken symbolic links. Once you actually add the framework bundles files to the project (from the built AudioKit source distribution), the placeholders disappear and are replaced with *AudioKit.framework* and *AudioKitUI.framework* group folders that contain a subfolder containing header files.